# cannot upload the file through admin panel

Tags: php, mysql

Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

```
public function file_upload($file,$dir)
    {
        $uploads_dir = $dir; 
        $original_file = addslashes($file['name']);         // storing file name
        $buffer_path = $file['tmp_name'];                   // storing temp buffer path
        $unique_name = time().$original_file;               // creating unique file name by appending time stamp 
        $path = $uploads_dir.$unique_name;

        // uploading file using default function
        if(move_uploaded_file($buffer_path,$path))
        {
            return $path;
        }
        else
        {
            return "No";
        }
    }

    function multiple_image_upload($file,$path)
    {
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($file);
        if(empty($file['name'][0]))
        {
            return "No file selected";
        }
        else 
        {
            $cnt = 0 ;
            foreach($file['name'] as $filename)
            {
                    $buffer_path = $file['tmp_name'][$cnt];
                    $unique_file_name = $path.date('Y-m-d H-i-s').time().$filename;
                    move_uploaded_file($buffer_path,$unique_file_name);
                    $final_file_path[] = $unique_file_name;
                    $cnt++;         
            }
            return $final_file_path;
        }   

    }

    function multiple_thumb($msg,$filedata,$thumb_folder)
    {       

            if(!is_dir($thumb_folder))
            {
                mkdir($thumb_folder,0755);
            }
            $cnt=0;
            foreach($msg as $val)
            {
                /* echo $val;
                echo "<br />"; */
                //echo "<pre>";
                //print_r($filedata['name']);
                $o_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($val);   
                $o_width = imageSX($o_image);
                $o_height = imageSY($o_image);


                    $n_width = 230;
                    $n_height = 250;


            $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($n_width,$n_height);  
            //print_r($new_image);
            imagecopyresampled($new_image,$o_image,0,0,0,0,$n_width,$n_height,$o_width,$o_height);

            $thumb_unique_path = $thumb_folder.date('Y-m-d H-i-s').time().$filedata['name'][$cnt];

            imagejpeg($new_image,$thumb_unique_path);
            $thumb_final_data[] = $thumb_unique_path;
            $cnt++;
            }
            //print_r($thumb_final_data);
            return $thumb_final_data;
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Column count is a mysql query ... error... what is your query?

Comment: `column count doesnt match` means no column names given in `insert` query and so the server "thinks" U mean ALL columns, check the manual `INSERT INTO table (column1,column2,column3)` VALUES ('one','two','three')` - this even work if the table has more than these 3 columns